# View Close/Re-open history of a question

Tags: discussion, support

I've recently closed a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43160762/retain-count-of-objects) as [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510913/objective-c-assign-copy-retain?noredirect=1&lq=1). A few minutes ago that question got reopened. I strongly believe that it is a duplicate question, so out of my curiosity I just went to that post for looking who re-opened that question and found that there is no way to get that information. If a question have edit history we can easily find the close and re-open history of a post by checking the edit history, in the above case there is no edit history, hence I couldn't find the details. Is there any way I can find the close/re-open history of a post which doesn't have an edit history ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43160762/timeline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is just no link to the revision history because the post has not been edited, but the revision history is still accessible at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43160762/revisions

Alternatively you can have a look at [the timeline of the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43160762/timeline).

Answer (score 5):

As of 2020 you can see post timeline by clicking at timeline icon below votes count:
[image]